# Sql error- due to blank space in column name

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am getting errors in a query and I think its just because of the blank spaces in the field names.

```
  rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].Description,[Sheet1$].Security FROM [Sheet1$]", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly

  rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].Description,[Sheet1$].(SEC 1) FROM [Sheet1$]", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

The first one runs fine, but the second one doesn't and basically throws error about "SEC 1" . Now all of these are column names and cannot be changed, so is there any thing which can solve it. Even putting column name in parenthesis is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need square brackets, not parenthesis.

Change `(SEC 1)` to `[SEC 1]`.